# Scale a column of a list-of-lists in Python

Tags: python, matrix

If I have a matrix as a simple array of arrays (not a numpy matrix), how could I scale one column of the matrix in just one line of code?

This is just out of curiosity - I'm not claiming there's any benefit to one line over two or three.

Here's what I have, for some matrix "mtx", column index "index" and scalar "scale". Can we make it prettier or more readable? Also, this could fail if multiple columns have the same values.

```
mtx = zip( * ( (map(lambda r : r*scale if zip(*mtx).index(col)==index else r, col)) for col in zip(*mtx)] ) )
```

Edit:

here's an example of input/out, as requested

```
mtx = [ [ i for i in range(3) ] for j in range(3) ]
index = 1
scale = 17
print mtx

mtx = zip( * ( p (map(lambda r : r*scale if zip(*mtx).index(col)==index else r, col)) for col in zip(*mtx)] ) )
print mtx
```

The print statements will produce, respectively:

```
--> [ [0,1,2],[0,1,2],[0,1,2] ]
--> [ [0,17,2],[0,17,2],[0,17,2] ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> [[j*((i==index)*(scale-1)+1) for i,j in enumerate(l)] for l in mtx]
[[0, 17, 2], [0, 17, 2], [0, 17, 2]]
```

Comment: I accepted this one because it was the more concise answer, though manji's looks good too

Answer (score 1):

```
[[row[i]*scale if i == index else row[i] for i in range(0, len(row))] for row in mtx]
```